How to disable the default Popup (context) menu using only the interceptor class?
The problem is as follows (using TEdit as an example). There is this code in the FMX.Edit.Style.pas file that calls the default context menu if no custom menu is assigned:
function TStyledEdit.ShowContextMenu(const ScreenPosition: TPointF): Boolean;
 
  function ShowDefaultMenu: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := False;
    if EditPopupMenu <> nil then
      try
        if Root <> nil then
          EditPopupMenu.Parent := Root.GetObject;
        Result := True;
        UpdatePopupMenuItems;
        if Model.CheckSpelling and (FSpellService <> nil) and (Length(FSpellingRegions) > 0) then
          UpdateSpellPopupMenu(ScreenToLocal(ScreenPosition));
        EditPopupMenu.PopupComponent := Self;
        EditPopupMenu.Popup(Round(ScreenPosition.X), Round(ScreenPosition.Y));
      finally
        EditPopupMenu.Parent := nil;
      end;
  end;
 
  function ShowUsersPopupMenu: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := IControl(PresentedControl).ShowContextMenu(ScreenPosition)
  end;
 
begin
  Result := False;
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    if Supports(PresentedControl, IControl) and (PresentedControl.PopupMenu <> nil) then
      Result := ShowUsersPopupMenu
    else
      Result := ShowDefaultMenu;
end;

Of course, you could just create an empty TPopupMenu and manually assign it to each control that has the PopupMenu property (as suggested in this answer). But how do you do this in a more professional way, by using an interceptor class?
I tried it that way:
namespace My_PopupMenu {
  class TPopupMenu : public Fmx::Menus::TPopupMenu {
    public:
      virtual void __fastcall Popup(float X, float Y) {
        ShowMessage("Popup");
      }
    };
};
#define TPopupMenu My_PopupMenu::TPopupMenu

However, the interception only works for those controls that have a custom PopupMenu manually assigned to them (via the PopupMenu property).
And this attempt gives the same result, but also works when pressing the VK_APPS key on the keyboard for Edits that have an empty PopupMenu property. Right-click is still not intercepted at all:
namespace My_Edit {
  class TEdit : public Fmx::Edit::TEdit {
    public:
      virtual bool __fastcall ShowContextMenu(const System::Types::TPointF &ScreenPosition) {
        ShowMessage("ShowContextMenu");
      }
    };
};
#define TEdit My_Edit::TEdit

Another option is to comment out some lines in the FMX.Edit.Style.pas file itself:
function TStyledEdit.ShowContextMenu(const ScreenPosition: TPointF): Boolean;
 
...
 
begin
  Result := False;
  { // You don't want this
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    if Supports(PresentedControl, IControl) and (PresentedControl.PopupMenu <> nil) then
      Result := ShowUsersPopupMenu
    else
      Result := ShowDefaultMenu;
  }
end;

And everything will work perfectly. But this is an even more amateurish approach.
What am I doing wrong?

"Right-click is still not intercepted at all" - I tried your code in 12.2, and the My_Edit::TEdit::ShowContextMenu() method IS called when right-clicking on the Edit control, but only when its ControlType is set to Styled, it is NOT called when its ControlType is Platform. Which makes sense, as IIRC FireMonkey doesn't handle the Win32 WM_CONTEXTMENU message at all.

@RemyLebeau In 10.4.2 and 11.2 (can't check it in 12.2 yet) this method is only called for the VK_APPS key even if ControlType is set to Styled, which is very strange.

IIRC Shift+F10 should also trigger it, too. But this is just one of many reasons why I don't use FireMonkey. It's too unstable/incomplete for my taste. Lots of basic things just don't work right.
